# Is it acceptable if two services interact with each other in Angular 2 application?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, service, structure

I have two services, for example:

RoomService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Room } from './room.model';

@Injectable()
export class RoomService {
  ...
  getRoom(): Room {
    return room;
  }
  ...
}
```

EventService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Event } from './event.model';
import { Room } from './room.model';
import { RoomService } from './room.service';

@Injectable()
export class RoomService {
  ...
  constructor(private roomService: RoomService) {}
  ...
  setEvent(): Event {
    const event: Event;
    event.room = this.roomService.getRoom();
    return event;
  }
  ...
}
```

Is it logically correct to use RoomService inside EventService?

Comment: yes, it's completely normal, as long as you can avoid circular dependencies

Comment: Yes. And what Hoff refers to is when you inject a service into a service that calls back the original service. You should never do that. A simple explanation of what that looks like RoomService uses the EventService. Then EventService uses RoomService. That's an example of circular dependency and should be avoided.